# Escribir directamente en el Select con JS en un CRUD

Tags: javascript, php, select

Mi asunto es el siguiente: una BD con 4 Tablas: General (id, nombre, idcolonia), Estado (id, Nombre), Ciudad (id, nombre, idestado) y Colonia (id, nombre, idciudad), los lleno en un PHP con 1 TextField (Nombre) y 3 Select (Estado, Ciudad, Colonia), el llenado y guardado sin problema. El detalle es al momento de buscar un Nombre guardado en la tabla "General", intento llenar el TextField y Los Select con la información almacenada para que el usuario los vea y los modifique, pero solo puedo llenar el TextField y el Select del Estado con JS, pero los Select de ciudad y colonia no se llenan ni accediendo al .value ni al .selectedIndex, no si tenga que ver la dependencia entre ellos, alguna idea por favor. pongo el ejemplo del llenado, lo hago igual para los 3 y solo funciona para el primero (de ambas maneras). Saludos y gracias de antemano.

```js
////////// JS para el llenado secuencial de los Select al momento de querer almacenar en el CRUD, esto funciona perfecto
const cbxEstado = document.getElementById('estado')
cbxEstado.addEventListener("change", getMunicipios)
const cbxMunicipio = document.getElementById('ciudad')
cbxMunicipio.addEventListener("change", getLocalidades)
const cbxLocalidad = document.getElementById('colonia')

function getColony(url, formData, targetElement) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        mode: 'cors'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            targetElement.innerHTML = data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
function fetchAndSetData(url, formData, targetElement) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        mode: 'cors'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            targetElement.innerHTML = data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
function getMunicipios() {
    let estado = cbxEstado.value;
    let url = 'Queries/getMunicipios.php';
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_estado', estado);

    fetchAndSetData(url, formData, cbxMunicipio)
        .then(() => {
            cbxLocalidad.innerHTML = ''
            let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
            defaultOption.value = 0;
            defaultOption.innerHTML = "Seleccionar";
            cbxLocalidad.appendChild(defaultOption);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
function getLocalidades() {
    let municipio = cbxMunicipio.value;
    let url = 'Queries/getLocalidades.php';
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_municipio', municipio);
    fetchAndSetData(url, formData, cbxLocalidad)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}


////////// Por si se requiere, esta parte es donde a partir de seleccionar un estado filtro las ciudades, todo bien al seleccionarlo.
<?php
require 'Connection.php';
$idEstado = $_POST['id_estado'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tcity WHERE idstate=$idEstado");
$respuesta = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar</option>";
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $respuesta .= "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>


////////// Por si se requiere, esta parte es donde a partir de seleccionar una ciudad filtro las colonias, también todo bien al seleccionarlo.
<?php
require 'Connection.php';
$idMunicipio = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id_municipio']);
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tcolony WHERE idcity=$idMunicipio");
$respuesta = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar</option>";
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $respuesta .= "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . ",     " . $row['settlement'] . "</option>";
}
echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>


////////// JS con la función la búsqueda predictiva de la información almacenada y mostrarla en el TextField y los Select, esto también funciona perfecto
document.getElementById("TSearch").addEventListener("keyup", getSchools)

function getSchools() {
    let inputCP = document.getElementById("TSearch").value
    let Tlist = document.getElementById("Tlist")

    if (inputCP.length > 0) {

        let url = "../Queries/getEscuelas.php"
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("TSearch", inputCP)

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            mode: "cors" //Default cors, no-cors, same-origin
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                Tlist.style.display = 'block'
                Tlist.innerHTML = data
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    } else {
        Tlist.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

////////// Aquí es donde ya no funciona, en la parte de la búsqueda de información almacenada, incluso colocando manualmente algún index o value, solo el 1er Select (el del estado) se llena, esto es para que el usuario vea su información previmante guardad y la pueda modificar.

function mostrar(id, name, colony) {
    Tlist.style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById("Name").value = name;
    document.getElementById("estado").selectedIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById("ciudad").selectedIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById("colonia").selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- PHP del formulario   -->
<form name="Data" method="post" action="../Queries/insert_School.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="LGData">
    <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Escribe el nombre de tu escuela" name="Name" required>
    <select name="estado" title="Selecciona el estado de la escuela" id="estado" required>
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        <?php while ($row = $estados->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select name="ciudad" title="Selecciona la ciudad de la escuela" id="ciudad">
        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    </select>
    <select name="colonia" size="1" title="Ingresa la colonia donde se ubica la escuela" id="colonia" style="display:block;width: 100%;height:27px;z-index:18;" tabindex="6" required>
        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: tengo una idea y espero que te guste, inicia haciendo el [tour] despues seguimos con las necesidades ya que he entendido el 50% de tu situacion el otro 50% estoy seguro que esta en el codigo que no has compartido

Comment: Gracias, es la primer pregunta que subo, espero hacerlo correctamente y compartir el código también. Gracias.

Comment: ok, aqui el problema esta en como se hacen las cosas... no me queda claro en que momento llenas el select con datos, si cuando haces la consulta o luego por ajax... esto es crucial saber manejarlo.

Comment: si traes todo armado en la consulta... entonces debes evaluar/debug que esta devolbiendo el query cuando intentas traer los datos y falla.

Comment: si lo llenas por ajax, entonces debes validar tanto en el js como en el php que toda la comunicacion y datos sean manejados hasta que se actualice el select...

Comment: Las funciones getMunicipios y getLocalidades las utilizo para que se elija, estado-ciudad-colonia al momento de guardar por primera vez, eso funciona bien, pero luego busco el nombre de la escuela y se deben llenar los 3 select, dependiendo de lo que se almacenó en la BD, ahí es donde el que permite elegir el estado si se llena con lo que se había almacenado, pero el de ciudad y colonia no se llenan, en BD la tabla Estado tiene una FK a la de Ciudades y esta a su vez a la de Colonias. pienso que por ahí debe estar el detalle.

Comment: necesitaria ver la estructura DDL de la base de datos.